# Adapt react native App for iphone X

Tags: react-native

I want to adapt my react-native app for iPhone X. I tried to use [SafeAreaView](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-iphonex-92ff511282af) but this added a space on both, the top and bottom area. The problem is that I do not need a space on the bottom. I tired to add a padding to the app

```
return (
  <MyApp style={{paddingTop:35}}/>
)
```

This looks nice but I am unable to change the color of the white space in this case. Is there any other solution?

Comment: i would also appreciate an upvote on my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shoud do the trick:

```
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ marginTop: 35, backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
    //insert all your components here 
    </View>
  </View>
```

[image: example]